# Parsing Float from char

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I have a problem for parsing float from char in JNI-Android Application.This char is a like data `vector<float>` from custom HOG https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG/wiki/trainHOG-Tutorial.  I want to detect my custom HOG Animal.  So this is one sample chars for +1 (Positive Image) from 49 data.

```
+1 1:0.0516209 2:0.0526671 3:0.0621273 4:0.162602 5:0.252267 6:0.220246 7:0.116933 8:0.0665012 9:0.040535 10:0.0810178 11:0.0799648 12:0.0989393 13:0.204468 14:0.252267 15:0.232619 16:0.10104 17:0.0503855 18:0.0872255 19:0.109535 20:0.135352 21:0.252267 22:0.252267 23:0.252267 24:0.19159 25:0.139957 26:0.0849861 27:0.0621954 28:0.180085 29:0.220934 30:0.252267 31:0.252267 32:0.252267 33:0.14686 34:0.133376 35:0.0798698 36:0.143804 37:0.154667 38:0.175837 39:0.175819 40:0.185156 41:0.242682 42:0.143323 43:0.0656771 44:0.0752698 45:0.120002 46:0.125042 47:0.137929 48:0.141668 49:0.238362 50:0.242682 51:0.187268 52:0.0587663 53:0.0820198 54:0.0561508 55:0.173739 56:0.235661 57:0.176866 58:0.242682 59:0.242682 60:0.120697 61:0.0926801 62:0.074838 63:0.120294 64:0.099418 65:0.165938 66:0.223667 67:0.242682 68:0.242682 69:0.242682 70:0.0941423 71:0.0576666 72:0.0232888 73:0.030905 74:0.0741619 75:0.128762 76:0.241179 77:0.284917 78:0.284917 79:0.0878371 80:0.057604 81:0.0254226 82:0.0749189 83:0.0660299 84:0.112901 85:0.165158 86:0.284917 87:0.205528 88:0.0918434 89:0.0600073 90:0.0772874 91:0.0374085 92:0.119716 93:0.183876 94:0.237916 95:0.284917 96:0.284917 97:0.11597 98:0.0431861 99:0.0226412 100:0.053028 101:0.0779262 102:0.138294 103:0.197107 104:0.284917 105:0.284917 106:0.155058 107:0.09058 108:0.0685508 109:0.107512 110:0.0580869 111:0.155158 112:0.243893 113:0.215341 114:0.129598 115:0.048822 116:0.0425757 117:0.0809534 118:0.1627 119:0.124774 120:0.198517 121:0.259591 122:0.259591 123:0.109071 124:0.0437223 125:0.0560505 126:0.0753148 127:0.0582958 128:0.0646337 129:0.207277 130:0.259591 131:0.248938 132:0.259591 133:0.135874 134:0.113958 135:0.061379 136:0.0877517 137:0.115159 138:0.223133 139:0.259591 140:0.259591 141:0.259591 142:0.135361 143:0.0905518 144:0.0649403 145:0.104641 146:0.139505 147:0.234039 148:0.234039 149:0.209601 150:0.213197 151:0.132382 152:0.0932568 153:0.0901358 154:0.185335 155:0.232361 156:0.234039 157:0.234039 158:0.154098 159:0.167337 160:0.179891 161:0.118966 162:0.131475 163:0.0564679 164:0.105363 165:0.167412 166:0.231988 167:0.228415 168:0.228708 169:0.104494 170:0.072458 171:0.0586462 172:0.0992585 173:0.117884 174:0.104316 175:0.151379 176:0.187837 177:0.156796 178:0.232444 179:0.139886 180:0.0964207 181:0.145255 182:0.198792 183:0.150749 184:0.221525 185:0.19881 186:0.178096 187:0.226074 188:0.121964 189:0.102861 190:0.0437534 191:0.131493 192:0.178541 193:0.21926 194:0.234759 195:0.254669 196:0.157603 197:0.0723847 198:0.0244493 199:0.065348 200:0.0853451 201:0.0624319 202:0.103251 203:0.139865 204:0.220055 205:0.254669 206:0.223438 207:0.0848672 208:0.0425032 209:0.0791857 210:0.138352 211:0.157657 212:0.200656 213:0.254669 214:0.254669 215:0.167132 216:0.0369475 217:0.0398139 218:0.124495 219:0.180236 220:0.185851 221:0.262945 222:0.262945 223:0.142996 224:0.09139 225:0.0423195 226:0.0673232 227:0.067754 228:0.118807 229:0.177049 230:0.217177 231:0.262945 232:0.206083 233:0.154343 234:0.129637 235:0.071941 236:0.0843471 237:0.154425 238:0.167051 239:0.223171 240:0.262945 241:0.230233 242:0.168113 243:0.0707214 244:0.0988057 245:0.110709 246:0.10464 247:0.170808 248:0.142613 249:0.198069 250:0.193661 251:0.206063 252:0.139514 253:0.070888 254:0.0546235 255:0.0987665 256:0.179403 257:0.176451 258:0.231507 259:0.170609 260:0.170777 261:0.134404 262:0.0957243 263:0.0741578 264:0.113292 265:0.210238 266:0.215958 267:0.264889 268:0.175568 269:0.120427 270:0.0934888 271:0.107025 272:0.127747 273:0.0658595 274:0.172265 275:0.187371 276:0.264889 277:0.179685 278:0.217699 279:0.124863 280:0.140482 281:0.0842961 282:0.0816219 283:0.186152 284:0.26147 285:0.264889 286:0.14057 287:0.18035 288:0.149876 289:0.0789043 290:0.170528 291:0.259454 292:0.244211 293:0.259454 294:0.255461 295:0.124829 296:0.0738446 297:0.0424127 298:0.197806 299:0.162143 300:0.144715 301:0.122082 302:0.171563 303:0.123079 304:0.188536 305:0.128817 306:0.0890725 307:0.0940822 308:0.185499 309:0.259454 310:0.252905 311:0.211187 312:0.161549 313:0.115569 314:0.0730725 315:0.0770362 316:0.226353 317:0.181456 318:0.223296 319:0.170029 320:0.117185 321:0.0981806 322:0.0746445 323:0.060523 324:0.0916957 325:0.0950073 326:0.0789168 327:0.0433256 328:0.0477858 329:0.109855 330:0.13269 331:0.207804 332:0.182029 333:0.0941013 334:0.118187 335:0.0871392 336:0.0667544 337:0.125589 338:0.256858 339:0.254672 340:0.256858 341:0.219227 342:0.102974 343:0.160436 344:0.140071 345:0.0956094 346:0.0954186 347:0.105212 348:0.0769432 349:0.134467 350:0.104214 351:0.153261 352:0.236158 353:0.218971 354:0.134611 355:0.232192 356:0.256858 357:0.160758 358:0.229581 359:0.215932 360:0.256858 361:0.131302 362:0.0838311 363:0.0680505 364:0.0964724 365:0.167542 366:0.163733 367:0.159702 368:0.11763 369:0.0803405 370:0.147074 371:0.153463 372:0.141674 373:0.108444 374:0.110367 375:0.155245 376:0.0968434 377:0.0853039 378:0.0769986 379:0.233289 380:0.184741 381:0.148944 382:0.195778 383:0.249193 384:0.148996 385:0.183793 386:0.157546 387:0.249193 388:0.249193 389:0.249193 390:0.249193 391:0.16308 392:0.180707 393:0.154442 394:0.126717 395:0.145393 396:0.249193 397:0.0897672 398:0.14826 399:0.16095 400:0.191101 401:0.183119 402:0.242813 403:0.0559302 404:0.0604032 405:0.0441353 406:0.0892086 407:0.0911337 408:0.0933983 409:0.204716 410:0.249644 411:0.24499 412:0.0836525 413:0.0743139 414:0.0867809 415:0.230095 416:0.209791 417:0.249644 418:0.249644 419:0.203505 420:0.169885 421:0.0601984 422:0.0619023 423:0.149432 424:0.095661 425:0.119704 426:0.185102 427:0.249644 428:0.249644 429:0.2331 430:0.172669 431:0.0571165 432:0.0554624 433:0.105544 434:0.124474 435:0.204209 436:0.149226 437:0.287671 438:0.233312 439:0.158538 440:0.085772 441:0.102165 442:0.117022 443:0.122671 444:0.160237 445:0.151971 446:0.143499 447:0.129942 448:0.0959389 449:0.0556028 450:0.0864025 451:0.167466 452:0.0568043 453:0.105169 454:0.28099 455:0.287671 456:0.287671 457:0.203573 458:0.0838686 459:0.125802 460:0.19001 461:0.0978778 462:0.118772 463:0.103927 464:0.206477 465:0.221949 466:0.147634 467:0.109453 468:0.21046 469:0.0934628 470:0.111775 471:0.0854255 472:0.0896416 473:0.0980298 474:0.0729928 475:0.101601 476:0.0468797 477:0.0791986 478:0.158492 479:0.162197 480:0.188256 481:0.310893 482:0.298819 483:0.152905 484:0.154461 485:0.104955 486:0.219529 487:0.105981 488:0.109796 489:0.0943929 490:0.116314 491:0.211338 492:0.183864 493:0.15099 494:0.0466525 495:0.0814759 496:0.0826441 497:0.133331 498:0.189644 499:0.310893 500:0.310893 501:0.310893 502:0.178649 503:0.0622459 504:0.0721505 505:0.161893 506:0.112677 507:0.17197 508:0.261516 509:0.231606 510:0.12838 511:0.119647 512:0.0897209 513:0.204429 514:0.258437 515:0.151017 516:0.232684 517:0.106046 518:0.119519 519:0.118933 520:0.102533 521:0.109681 522:0.261516 523:0.0781687 524:0.0865439 525:0.120502 526:0.261516 527:0.261516 528:0.261516 529:0.0982907 530:0.0651658 531:0.0631546 532:0.205084 533:0.151398 534:0.215174 535:0.0894046 536:0.133384 537:0.157612 538:0.100458 539:0.0809739 540:0.148817 541:0.239039 542:0.163965 543:0.24837 544:0.147138 545:0.137003 546:0.198188 547:0.0955781 548:0.0704638 549:0.201737 550:0.09251 551:0.13307 552:0.203236 553:0.230284 554:0.24581 555:0.24837 556:0.163676 557:0.0441309 558:0.05486 559:0.200242 560:0.18874 561:0.24837 562:0.122286 563:0.111089 564:0.170059 565:0.0974838 566:0.0557162 567:0.139893 568:0.142029 569:0.135066 570:0.239535 571:0.165015 572:0.151529 573:0.215339 574:0.109499 575:0.0477798 576:0.102104 577:0.142869 578:0.0506508 579:0.099281 580:0.311296 581:0.311296 582:0.29235 583:0.0853785 584:0.0298867 585:0.0839334 586:0.217339 587:0.102943 588:0.0936696 589:0.0937782 590:0.148731 591:0.120643 592:0.0644866 593:0.105494 594:0.223154 595:0.124304 596:0.0630043 597:0.0882641 598:0.290856 599:0.311296 600:0.311296 601:0.159524 602:0.0136488 603:0.0657668 604:0.204307 605:0.149414 606:0.111302 607:0.106827 608:0.11079 609:0.117657 610:0.0400945 611:0.0877738 612:0.183063 613:0.133036 614:0.11257 615:0.114527 616:0.079359 617:0.144871 618:0.166868 619:0.0980467 620:0.0701586 621:0.136393 622:0.144127 623:0.204131 624:0.184349 625:0.273352 626:0.273352 627:0.273352 628:0.117483 629:0.0403787 630:0.101049 631:0.154879 632:0.180959 633:0.167622 634:0.138856 635:0.0361039 636:0.0806388 637:0.0373684 638:0.0916881 639:0.156742 640:0.223871 641:0.273352 642:0.271826 643:0.273352 644:0.165789 645:0.124406 646:0.0731598 647:0.143914 648:0.174675 649:0.112238 650:0.164751 651:0.0874189 652:0.161027 653:0.280177 654:0.223749 655:0.0456342 656:0.0362706 657:0.0407592 658:0.236262 659:0.280177 660:0.280177 661:0.0951557 662:0.137062 663:0.0833213 664:0.0380415 665:0.0730444 666:0.0742162 667:0.173875 668:0.280177 669:0.210483 670:0.195704 671:0.156123 672:0.0756225 673:0.0553245 674:0.106288 675:0.11255 676:0.231428 677:0.280177 678:0.280177 679:0.132035 680:0.0793173 681:0.0650503 682:0.0857836 683:0.126709 684:0.141397 685:0.215868 686:0.298669 687:0.298669 688:0.208136 689:0.0907796 690:0.0632681 691:0.0523893 692:0.0769242 693:0.0955798 694:0.0874953 695:0.098873 696:0.244548 697:0.186292 698:0.111636 699:0.105521 700:0.0849176 701:0.0982519 702:0.0771137 703:0.180454 704:0.298669 705:0.298669 706:0.255643 707:0.0955855 708:0.0588408 709:0.0775926 710:0.161626 711:0.132766 712:0.078477 713:0.0844616 714:0.298669 715:0.242583 716:0.107347 717:0.0798445 718:0.0853468 719:0.103689 720:0.065806 721:0.0357221 722:0.0298848 723:0.0814559 724:0.167687 725:0.266033 726:0.266033 727:0.250278 728:0.0899015 729:0.0693378 730:0.074513 731:0.0717591 732:0.120642 733:0.0856944 734:0.0741726 735:0.111318 736:0.0733351 737:0.111474 738:0.102383 739:0.0333341 740:0.0476535 741:0.090083 742:0.119321 743:0.266033 744:0.266033 745:0.266033 746:0.266033 747:0.186286 748:0.126744 749:0.0692135 750:0.161342 751:0.110722 752:0.266033 753:0.180974 754:0.180172 755:0.266033 756:0.23479 757:0.117383 758:0.159488 759:0.246485 760:0.240844 761:0.0489906 762:0.0327636 763:0.0302243 764:0.0614286 765:0.0963371 766:0.174301 767:0.246485 768:0.246485 769:0.246485 770:0.0998213 771:0.0707082 772:0.0477948 773:0.138016 774:0.121114 775:0.204169 776:0.113 777:0.246485 778:0.220392 779:0.246485 780:0.113499 781:0.046402 782:0.0894608 783:0.168363 784:0.192057 785:0.17405 786:0.246485 787:0.221395 788:0.227333 789:0.139138 790:0.0606163 791:0.0669251 792:0.162615 793:0.168169 794:0.264854 795:0.243766 796:0.140564 797:0.0976328 798:0.0677347 799:0.0445176 800:0.15511 801:0.15869 802:0.264854 803:0.264854 804:0.246155 805:0.104299 806:0.0436364 807:0.0780234 808:0.131923 809:0.166165 810:0.2136 811:0.132863 812:0.238265 813:0.157387 814:0.103066 815:0.151245 816:0.096932 817:0.0574446 818:0.107677 819:0.132774 820:0.238755 821:0.264854 822:0.112574 823:0.141528 824:0.182357 825:0.106048 826:0.12458 827:0.150181 828:0.164209 829:0.24785 830:0.24785 831:0.24785 832:0.191579 833:0.0602815 834:0.0766117 835:0.118639 836:0.180041 837:0.177137 838:0.0915748 839:0.10766 840:0.24785 841:0.199659 842:0.0899677 843:0.130194 844:0.105077 845:0.0814451 846:0.0724681 847:0.220688 848:0.24785 849:0.145892 850:0.207808 851:0.151263 852:0.0936182 853:0.13452 854:0.151408 855:0.202105 856:0.107693 857:0.143771 858:0.233332 859:0.201684 860:0.184008 861:0.147185 862:0.120236 863:0.101269 864:0.155512
```

This is a one sample data char for -1 (Negative Image) from 22 data

```
-1 1:0.202916 2:0.238127 3:0.128888 4:0.137708 5:0.155601 6:0.105077 7:0.0983977 8:0.0843581 9:0.10491 10:0.238127 11:0.193283 12:0.115676 13:0.0532577 14:0.128305 15:0.112788 16:0.1271 17:0.143537 18:0.18471 19:0.142134 20:0.238127 21:0.139083 22:0.118682 23:0.238127 24:0.202205 25:0.147178 26:0.216429 27:0.0681436 28:0.20095 29:0.238127 30:0.196387 31:0.0990107 32:0.184812 33:0.178951 34:0.191704 35:0.230855 36:0.0895278 37:0.244468 38:0.15381 39:0.102552 40:0.0984278 41:0.227776 42:0.15434 43:0.0989782 44:0.19254 45:0.244468 46:0.0932954 47:0.0564859 48:0.0652223 49:0.193186 50:0.244468 51:0.195653 52:0.0678904 53:0.075226 54:0.0637843 55:0.240463 56:0.223208 57:0.189486 58:0.140949 59:0.148009 60:0.166039 61:0.198906 62:0.231404 63:0.142599 64:0.112919 65:0.104909 66:0.168501 67:0.244468 68:0.244468 69:0.135938 70:0.119736 71:0.0904195 72:0.082083 73:0.0307629 74:0.0312645 75:0.0487461 76:0.261841 77:0.282171 78:0.213438 79:0.0536121 80:0.0518256 81:0.0342206 82:0.0217149 83:0.0546434 84:0.0925523 85:0.244762 86:0.282171 87:0.282171 88:0.0968079 89:0.0927951 90:0.0540228 91:0.0481936 92:0.0557246 93:0.160169 94:0.282171 95:0.282171 96:0.24888 97:0.0563694 98:0.0597031 99:0.0795414 100:0.0643808 101:0.0684838 102:0.101178 103:0.282171 104:0.282171 105:0.282171 106:0.0793248 107:0.0722633 108:0.0745563 109:0.0101671 110:0.0276036 111:0.127687 112:0.262004 113:0.275387 114:0.245632 115:0.0609076 116:0.0512514 117:0.028738 118:0.0580375 119:0.0282748 120:0.211778 121:0.275387 122:0.275387 123:0.240033 124:0.0521407 125:0.0386775 126:0.0494758 127:0.0480672 128:0.0498178 129:0.126303 130:0.213497 131:0.275387 132:0.259392 133:0.0623863 134:0.0584124 135:0.0302611 136:0.0335715 137:0.0208229 138:0.183583 139:0.265358 140:0.275387 141:0.275387 142:0.1205 143:0.0981494 144:0.0628459 145:0.109558 146:0.177318 147:0.0987865 148:0.0929232 149:0.21123 150:0.154632 151:0.107868 152:0.214756 153:0.108362 154:0.0714979 155:0.209598 156:0.149005 157:0.171135 158:0.219599 159:0.19332 160:0.157791 161:0.219599 162:0.0952607 163:0.131616 164:0.21878 165:0.190347 166:0.103918 167:0.109131 168:0.0903577 169:0.0757711 170:0.137984 171:0.219599 172:0.114108 173:0.219599 174:0.213487 175:0.206846 176:0.219599 177:0.172328 178:0.129206 179:0.178524 180:0.219599 181:0.0577419 182:0.155792 183:0.123421 184:0.176922 185:0.230393 186:0.203766 187:0.230393 188:0.22723 189:0.0913815 190:0.0649546 191:0.0973571 192:0.168345 193:0.230393 194:0.170253 195:0.118387 196:0.165572 197:0.113887 198:0.0749892 199:0.0396387 200:0.123303 201:0.158325 202:0.230393 203:0.230393 204:0.230393 205:0.204921 206:0.175129 207:0.125109 208:0.035194 209:0.0551479 210:0.148492 211:0.230393 212:0.230393 213:0.223908 214:0.155903 215:0.161129 216:0.0972978 217:0.0636359 218:0.0474713 219:0.175701 220:0.2591 221:0.2591 222:0.160876 223:0.0781598 224:0.0768989 225:0.0748914 226:0.10912 227:0.0519005 228:0.114402 229:0.24724 230:0.2591 231:0.25836 232:0.0837505 233:0.0631729 234:0.0720033 235:0.0555216 236:0.0236018 237:0.10125 238:0.2591 239:0.2591 240:0.219502 241:0.241907 242:0.163548 243:0.0839565 244:0.0881268 245:0.0503224 246:0.0498073 247:0.216185 248:0.2591 249:0.2591 250:0.214226 251:0.0926044 252:0.0816564 253:0.112619 254:0.0605715 255:0.141974 256:0.214129 257:0.257826 258:0.217006 259:0.0719633 260:0.0620509 261:0.0397661 262:0.0786594 263:0.063506 264:0.184286 265:0.236293 266:0.257826 267:0.257826 268:0.153774 269:0.118041 270:0.0951895 271:0.124074 272:0.0842194 273:0.094113 274:0.160672 275:0.257826 276:0.257826 277:0.111546 278:0.0530195 279:0.0554362 280:0.104514 281:0.123719 282:0.257826 283:0.230009 284:0.257826 285:0.220973 286:0.140466 287:0.0902431 288:0.118578 289:0.13191 290:0.176977 291:0.234451 292:0.132086 293:0.0673623 294:0.0843796 295:0.132341 296:0.1946 297:0.206191 298:0.125072 299:0.192002 300:0.234451 301:0.234451 302:0.148904 303:0.120588 304:0.114092 305:0.163777 306:0.175541 307:0.101147 308:0.125462 309:0.164906 310:0.162793 311:0.134718 312:0.133301 313:0.234451 314:0.234451 315:0.128525 316:0.110798 317:0.0944765 318:0.218814 319:0.234451 320:0.201594 321:0.12267 322:0.213044 323:0.146956 324:0.0916341 325:0.0467531 326:0.0979971 327:0.179889 328:0.261865 329:0.18782 330:0.18751 331:0.122321 332:0.0982152 333:0.0896316 334:0.0292257 335:0.0284248 336:0.137201 337:0.261865 338:0.261865 339:0.261865 340:0.194944 341:0.0918262 342:0.0595214 343:0.0591814 344:0.0803219 345:0.208379 346:0.254768 347:0.166724 348:0.123515 349:0.186031 350:0.110829 351:0.0965476 352:0.0371847 353:0.0504509 354:0.154525 355:0.206632 356:0.261865 357:0.261865 358:0.261865 359:0.0722217 360:0.0800643 361:0.0409688 362:0.0176752 363:0.0569232 364:0.283295 365:0.283295 366:0.259439 367:0.283295 368:0.105985 369:0.0497671 370:0.0789917 371:0.0362733 372:0.0236163 373:0.146088 374:0.232727 375:0.210617 376:0.206419 377:0.0691863 378:0.0658879 379:0.0402945 380:0.0286892 381:0.0559084 382:0.191715 383:0.283295 384:0.283295 385:0.283295 386:0.0868175 387:0.0366786 388:0.110066 389:0.0266581 390:0.0233228 391:0.119706 392:0.252106 393:0.242942 394:0.190844 395:0.064017 396:0.0875403 397:0.166629 398:0.0899554 399:0.0677852 400:0.119023 401:0.250455 402:0.223322 403:0.184076 404:0.0784621 405:0.0816593 406:0.110259 407:0.139618 408:0.250455 409:0.151872 410:0.250455 411:0.187937 412:0.217633 413:0.127164 414:0.113712 415:0.189946 416:0.0618852 417:0.0649265 418:0.150097 419:0.218379 420:0.155659 421:0.155087 422:0.0815997 423:0.143141 424:0.122289 425:0.102314 426:0.250455 427:0.220619 428:0.250455 429:0.151841 430:0.169793 431:0.135818 432:0.178764 433:0.162701 434:0.102889 435:0.0567895 436:0.129393 437:0.149302 438:0.177379 439:0.239908 440:0.169264 441:0.149341 442:0.0779376 443:0.0355276 444:0.113565 445:0.245542 446:0.184525 447:0.159865 448:0.177483 449:0.0998318 450:0.0939305 451:0.213265 452:0.15501 453:0.117276 454:0.196975 455:0.245542 456:0.245542 457:0.181286 458:0.122424 459:0.178347 460:0.0853598 461:0.0776414 462:0.123375 463:0.245542 464:0.245542 465:0.245542 466:0.12568 467:0.124069 468:0.157908 469:0.0483786 470:0.0488987 471:0.133479 472:0.20808 473:0.132927 474:0.0863621 475:0.143265 476:0.0962188 477:0.0682617 478:0.0375666 479:0.0391207 480:0.0866582 481:0.165039 482:0.255371 483:0.255371 484:0.243334 485:0.0814715 486:0.0753955 487:0.0936942 488:0.129051 489:0.1357 490:0.24164 491:0.255371 492:0.153412 493:0.174077 494:0.255371 495:0.103484 496:0.111238 497:0.0902079 498:0.0954442 499:0.255371 500:0.255371 501:0.255371 502:0.203751 503:0.237107 504:0.110315 505:0.0526282 506:0.0322868 507:0.0423939 508:0.184663 509:0.297181 510:0.297181 511:0.251596 512:0.106993 513:0.0522684 514:0.0625633 515:0.0295701 516:0.0552298 517:0.159044 518:0.258566 519:0.201533 520:0.100106 521:0.0897315 522:0.0890958 523:0.0922364 524:0.0613719 525:0.0807405 526:0.297181 527:0.297181 528:0.297181 529:0.138955 530:0.151343 531:0.125865 532:0.0558962 533:0.0610004 534:0.12525 535:0.196676 536:0.238344 537:0.214618 538:0.0837075 539:0.112279 540:0.105342 541:0.0982794 542:0.0411905 543:0.0932071 544:0.197392 545:0.235027 546:0.128419 547:0.0539251 548:0.0599048 549:0.121678 550:0.151401 551:0.0705359 552:0.205576 553:0.260876 554:0.264424 555:0.21007 556:0.0857578 557:0.0984105 558:0.177422 559:0.124249 560:0.0727931 561:0.151987 562:0.248837 563:0.241573 564:0.157753 565:0.0715951 566:0.0821431 567:0.129323 568:0.211749 569:0.101268 570:0.124817 571:0.264424 572:0.264424 573:0.264424 574:0.0945323 575:0.0944857 576:0.169243 577:0.0977583 578:0.0973214 579:0.090172 580:0.14533 581:0.258168 582:0.219136 583:0.211844 584:0.182759 585:0.0851776 586:0.0491024 587:0.10393 588:0.097326 589:0.215013 590:0.258168 591:0.24219 592:0.114956 593:0.144647 594:0.147168 595:0.0887443 596:0.0919797 597:0.0948256 598:0.129122 599:0.206411 600:0.170214 601:0.196858 602:0.155078 603:0.131503 604:0.0524837 605:0.121219 606:0.176196 607:0.228174 608:0.258168 609:0.204058 610:0.132163 611:0.169165 612:0.224304 613:0.0874906 614:0.146734 615:0.0862 616:0.170733 617:0.228861 618:0.152198 619:0.150799 620:0.228861 621:0.165516 622:0.104408 623:0.136736 624:0.0724613 625:0.195694 626:0.228861 627:0.134728 628:0.138115 629:0.228861 630:0.104284 631:0.0729019 632:0.123573 633:0.200347 634:0.205191 635:0.228861 636:0.185752 637:0.120049 638:0.19879 639:0.228861 640:0.0772772 641:0.110958 642:0.0920094 643:0.142821 644:0.201881 645:0.195723 646:0.134162 647:0.228861 648:0.187852 649:0.0736535 650:0.112542 651:0.12742 652:0.247577 653:0.247577 654:0.205901 655:0.107634 656:0.135854 657:0.0954487 658:0.0599283 659:0.0793993 660:0.173128 661:0.225048 662:0.205814 663:0.19194 664:0.101191 665:0.073265 666:0.0790001 667:0.0507331 668:0.104515 669:0.130859 670:0.238863 671:0.247577 672:0.238513 673:0.186152 674:0.217666 675:0.115738 676:0.0912129 677:0.106256 678:0.213899 679:0.219618 680:0.216841 681:0.223208 682:0.203846 683:0.0998502 684:0.0652137 685:0.119432 686:0.07891 687:0.147334 688:0.203575 689:0.185982 690:0.171594 691:0.104885 692:0.0709552 693:0.108609 694:0.137597 695:0.0881497 696:0.105485 697:0.256408 698:0.256408 699:0.256408 700:0.133865 701:0.0892009 702:0.108723 703:0.170078 704:0.0887182 705:0.19433 706:0.203472 707:0.256408 708:0.182657 709:0.121228 710:0.0930586 711:0.0820534 712:0.135671 713:0.0920392 714:0.178516 715:0.220795 716:0.256408 717:0.256408 718:0.207581 719:0.130461 720:0.0700859 721:0.119967 722:0.0945054 723:0.108038 724:0.158225 725:0.172115 726:0.149503 727:0.130036 728:0.0788522 729:0.136299 730:0.165995 731:0.139473 732:0.226551 733:0.220402 734:0.226551 735:0.205696 736:0.121995 737:0.12631 738:0.178081 739:0.200992 740:0.171977 741:0.170857 742:0.15123 743:0.223725 744:0.132559 745:0.146245 746:0.124028 747:0.149996 748:0.226551 749:0.123297 750:0.191264 751:0.165222 752:0.226551 753:0.221732 754:0.145904 755:0.10998 756:0.166489 757:0.128567 758:0.1069 759:0.237328 760:0.185708 761:0.218447 762:0.237578 763:0.152745 764:0.131531 765:0.141455 766:0.089619 767:0.0690976 768:0.113697 769:0.160673 770:0.16654 771:0.237578 772:0.153539 773:0.212842 774:0.1972 775:0.151109 776:0.0810687 777:0.134095 778:0.106552 779:0.237578 780:0.237578 781:0.204477 782:0.0675014 783:0.0740456 784:0.109949 785:0.103149 786:0.180932 787:0.167196 788:0.237578 789:0.237578 790:0.173121 791:0.0906037 792:0.11224 793:0.0537041 794:0.0835037 795:0.14455 796:0.226888 797:0.240534 798:0.223111 799:0.137546 800:0.156178 801:0.161526 802:0.0745361 803:0.102077 804:0.163531 805:0.158682 806:0.241481 807:0.205895 808:0.136551 809:0.072126 810:0.0728925 811:0.0815823 812:0.146696 813:0.243165 814:0.243165 815:0.243165 816:0.143359 817:0.135239 818:0.0858351 819:0.168148 820:0.0971405 821:0.137365 822:0.243165 823:0.23676 824:0.243165 825:0.187543 826:0.0802433 827:0.0949731 828:0.0850998 829:0.110978 830:0.0744459 831:0.134252 832:0.131017 833:0.197098 834:0.142086 835:0.123014 836:0.0888997 837:0.059911 838:0.117134 839:0.121659 840:0.159152 841:0.192528 842:0.258118 843:0.220797 844:0.152312 845:0.0888315 846:0.0572962 847:0.135076 848:0.106097 849:0.216091 850:0.232898 851:0.258118 852:0.133905 853:0.109726 854:0.133614 855:0.0852246 856:0.160699 857:0.231338 858:0.213403 859:0.258118 860:0.258118 861:0.258118 862:0.165642 863:0.0809806 864:0.0845187
```

So I want to parsing it from chars to float and then I want to use that for `hog.setSVMdetector(const vector<float>& detector);`

This is my code for parsing.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <android/log.h>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <opencv2/ml/ml.hpp>


#define LOG_TAG "TourGuide"
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))


typedef struct {
    char index[2]; ////for example 1-99
    char filler[1]; //for ":"
    float value;  // for "0.0516209"
    char space[1]; // for " "
}img_vector;

typedef struct {
    char img_type[2];
    char space[1];
    img_vector value[61344];
} img_dat;


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


vector<float> parseToVector(char* data_i)
{
   int i=0;
   vector<float> temp_vect;
   char temp_buf[20971520];
   int cur_vector =0 ;
   char temp_float[8+1]; // assume float max 11 digit
   memset(temp_float,0, sizeof(temp_float));
   char temp_index[2+1];
   memset(temp_index, 0, sizeof(temp_index));
   int state = 0; //when getting data, there's 3 state
   //state 0 -> getting index
   // state 1 -> getting filler ':'
   // state 2 -> getting float
   // state 3 -> getting space
   img_dat images;
   int data_length = strlen(data_i);
   memset(temp_buf, 0, sizeof(temp_buf));
   memcpy(temp_buf, data_i, data_length);

   //get img_type

   memcpy((char*)&images.img_type, temp_buf, 3); // get +1 and space
   data_length -= 3; //already parsed 3 bytes of data
   //i start from string number 3
   for (i =3; i<data_length; i++){
       if(state == 0) {
            if (temp_buf[i] != ':'){
                temp_index[strlen(temp_index)] = temp_buf[i];
            }
            else {
                memcpy(images.value[cur_vector].index, temp_index, strlen(temp_index));
                memset(temp_index,0, sizeof(temp_index));
                state = 1;
                i--; // step back
            }
       } else if (state == 1){
            if (temp_buf[i] == ':'){
                memcpy(images.value[cur_vector].filler, (char*)&temp_buf[i], 1);
                state = 2;
            }
       } else if (state == 2){
            if ((temp_buf[i] != ' ') &&  strlen(temp_float) < 12){
                temp_float[strlen(temp_float)] = temp_buf[i];
            }
            else {
                images.value[cur_vector].value = atof(temp_float);

                memset(temp_float, 0, sizeof(temp_float));
                state = 3;
                    i--; //step back
            }

       } else if (state ==3) {
            if (temp_buf[i] == ' '){
                memcpy(images.value[cur_vector].space, (char*)&temp_buf[i], 1);
                state = 0;
                cur_vector++;
            }

       }

   }
   for (int j =0; j<cur_vector;j++){
        temp_vect[j] = images.value[cur_vector].value;
   }

   return temp_vect;
}


extern "C"
jboolean
Java_com_example_franksyesipangkar_tourguide_CameraPreview_ImageProcessing
(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint width, jint height, jbyteArray NV21FrameData, jintArray outPixels, jbyteArray s)


{

LOGD("JNIEnv");

    //convert jbyteArray to char
    jbyte *cmd = env->GetByteArrayElements(s, 0);
    LOGD("JNIEnvFeature");


    //char * feature = (char *)cmd;
    char feature[819000];//[819000] 800kb for size file
    memset(feature,0, sizeof(feature));
    //memcpy(feature, cmd, strlen((char*)cmd));
    memcpy(feature, cmd+1024, 1024);   


        vector<float> VFeature;
        VFeature = parseToVector(feature);
        LOGD("ParseToVector");
```

When I run/debug it in Android Studio, I have an error in `logcat.I` think in this process

```
vector<float> VFeature;
            VFeature = parseToVector(feature);
```

I get the following error:

```
12-24 22:42:54.696  29947-30010/? E/TopActivity﹕ -com.example.franksyesipangkar.tourguide
12-24 22:42:54.782    2667-2667/? E/﹕ appName=com.example.franksyesipangkar.tourguide, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
12-24 22:42:55.666    2667-2667/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xbd86a624 (code=1), thread 2667 (ngkar.tourguide)
12-24 22:42:56.056  21711-21754/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '42d398e0 com.example.franksyesipangkar.tourguide/com.example.franksyesipangkar.tourguide.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!


12-24 22:44:30.395    2882-2882/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 00058435  /data/app-lib/com.example.franksyesipangkar.tourguide-1/libImageProcessing.so (parseToVector(char*)+64)
```

What do you think for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is that in `img_vector` you only allocate space for a 2 digit index(`char index[2]; ////for example 1-99`) but the indexes in your data go up to 3 digits.

That said the way you are extracting the floats from the file looks like a big mess.  If you only need to get all f the floating point numbers from one of those lines then you can use

```
std::string line = "+1 1:0.0516209 2:0.0526671 3:0.0621273 4:0.162602 5:0.252267 6:0.220246 7:0.116933 8:0.0665012 9:0.040535 10:0.0810178 11:0.0799648 12:0.0989393 13:0.204468 14:0.252267 15:0.232619 16:0.10104 17:0.0503855 18:0.0872255 19:0.109535 20:0.135352 21:0.252267 22:0.252267 23:0.252267 24:0.19159 25:0.139957 26:0.0849861 27:0.0621954 28:0.180085 29:0.220934 30:0.252267 31:0.252267 32:0.252267 33:0.14686 34:0.133376 35:0.0798698 36:0.143804 37:0.154667 38:0.175837 39:0.175819 40:0.185156 41:0.242682 42:0.143323 43:0.0656771 44:0.0752698 45:0.120002 46:0.125042 47:0.137929 48:0.141668 49:0.238362 50:0.242682 51:0.187268 52:0.0587663 53:0.0820198 54:0.0561508 55:0.173739 56:0.235661 57:0.176866 58:0.242682 59:0.242682 60:0.120697 61:0.0926801 62:0.074838 63:0.120294 64:0.099418 65:0.165938 66:0.223667 67:0.242682 68:0.242682 69:0.242682 70:0.0941423 71:0.0576666 72:0.0232888 73:0.030905 74:0.0741619 75:0.128762 76:0.241179 77:0.284917 78:0.284917 79:0.0878371 80:0.057604 81:0.0254226 82:0.0749189 83:0.0660299 84:0.112901 85:0.165158 86:0.284917 87:0.205528 88:0.0918434 89:0.0600073 90:0.0772874 91:0.0374085 92:0.119716 93:0.183876 94:0.237916 95:0.284917 96:0.284917 97:0.11597 98:0.0431861 99:0.0226412 100:0.053028 101:0.0779262 102:0.138294 103:0.197107 104:0.284917 105:0.284917 106:0.155058 107:0.09058 108:0.0685508 109:0.107512 110:0.0580869 111:0.155158 112:0.243893 113:0.215341 114:0.129598 115:0.048822 116:0.0425757 117:0.0809534 118:0.1627 119:0.124774 120:0.198517 121:0.259591 122:0.259591 123:0.109071 124:0.0437223 125:0.0560505 126:0.0753148 127:0.0582958 128:0.0646337 129:0.207277 130:0.259591 131:0.248938 132:0.259591 133:0.135874 134:0.113958 135:0.061379 136:0.0877517 137:0.115159 138:0.223133 139:0.259591 140:0.259591 141:0.259591 142:0.135361 143:0.0905518 144:0.0649403 145:0.104641 146:0.139505 147:0.234039 148:0.234039 149:0.209601 150:0.213197 151:0.132382 152:0.0932568 153:0.0901358 154:0.185335 155:0.232361 156:0.234039 157:0.234039 158:0.154098 159:0.167337 160:0.179891 161:0.118966 162:0.131475 163:0.0564679 164:0.105363 165:0.167412 166:0.231988 167:0.228415 168:0.228708 169:0.104494 170:0.072458 171:0.0586462 172:0.0992585 173:0.117884 174:0.104316 175:0.151379 176:0.187837 177:0.156796 178:0.232444 179:0.139886 180:0.0964207 181:0.145255 182:0.198792 183:0.150749 184:0.221525 185:0.19881 186:0.178096 187:0.226074 188:0.121964 189:0.102861 190:0.0437534 191:0.131493 192:0.178541 193:0.21926 194:0.234759 195:0.254669 196:0.157603 197:0.0723847 198:0.0244493 199:0.065348 200:0.0853451 201:0.0624319 202:0.103251 203:0.139865 204:0.220055 205:0.254669 206:0.223438 207:0.0848672 208:0.0425032 209:0.0791857 210:0.138352 211:0.157657 212:0.200656 213:0.254669 214:0.254669 215:0.167132 216:0.0369475 217:0.0398139 218:0.124495 219:0.180236 220:0.185851 221:0.262945 222:0.262945 223:0.142996 224:0.09139 225:0.0423195 226:0.0673232 227:0.067754 228:0.118807 229:0.177049 230:0.217177 231:0.262945 232:0.206083 233:0.154343 234:0.129637 235:0.071941 236:0.0843471 237:0.154425 238:0.167051 239:0.223171 240:0.262945 241:0.230233 242:0.168113 243:0.0707214 244:0.0988057 245:0.110709 246:0.10464 247:0.170808 248:0.142613 249:0.198069 250:0.193661 251:0.206063 252:0.139514 253:0.070888 254:0.0546235 255:0.0987665 256:0.179403 257:0.176451 258:0.231507 259:0.170609 260:0.170777 261:0.134404 262:0.0957243 263:0.0741578 264:0.113292 265:0.210238 266:0.215958 267:0.264889 268:0.175568 269:0.120427 270:0.0934888 271:0.107025 272:0.127747 273:0.0658595 274:0.172265 275:0.187371 276:0.264889 277:0.179685 278:0.217699 279:0.124863 280:0.140482 281:0.0842961 282:0.0816219 283:0.186152 284:0.26147 285:0.264889 286:0.14057 287:0.18035 288:0.149876 289:0.0789043 290:0.170528 291:0.259454 292:0.244211 293:0.259454 294:0.255461 295:0.124829 296:0.0738446 297:0.0424127 298:0.197806 299:0.162143 300:0.144715 301:0.122082 302:0.171563 303:0.123079 304:0.188536 305:0.128817 306:0.0890725 307:0.0940822 308:0.185499 309:0.259454 310:0.252905 311:0.211187 312:0.161549 313:0.115569 314:0.0730725 315:0.0770362 316:0.226353 317:0.181456 318:0.223296 319:0.170029 320:0.117185 321:0.0981806 322:0.0746445 323:0.060523 324:0.0916957 325:0.0950073 326:0.0789168 327:0.0433256 328:0.0477858 329:0.109855 330:0.13269 331:0.207804 332:0.182029 333:0.0941013 334:0.118187 335:0.0871392 336:0.0667544 337:0.125589 338:0.256858 339:0.254672 340:0.256858 341:0.219227 342:0.102974 343:0.160436 344:0.140071 345:0.0956094 346:0.0954186 347:0.105212 348:0.0769432 349:0.134467 350:0.104214 351:0.153261 352:0.236158 353:0.218971 354:0.134611 355:0.232192 356:0.256858 357:0.160758 358:0.229581 359:0.215932 360:0.256858 361:0.131302 362:0.0838311 363:0.0680505 364:0.0964724 365:0.167542 366:0.163733 367:0.159702 368:0.11763 369:0.0803405 370:0.147074 371:0.153463 372:0.141674 373:0.108444 374:0.110367 375:0.155245 376:0.0968434 377:0.0853039 378:0.0769986 379:0.233289 380:0.184741 381:0.148944 382:0.195778 383:0.249193 384:0.148996 385:0.183793 386:0.157546 387:0.249193 388:0.249193 389:0.249193 390:0.249193 391:0.16308 392:0.180707 393:0.154442 394:0.126717 395:0.145393 396:0.249193 397:0.0897672 398:0.14826 399:0.16095 400:0.191101 401:0.183119 402:0.242813 403:0.0559302 404:0.0604032 405:0.0441353 406:0.0892086 407:0.0911337 408:0.0933983 409:0.204716 410:0.249644 411:0.24499 412:0.0836525 413:0.0743139 414:0.0867809 415:0.230095 416:0.209791 417:0.249644 418:0.249644 419:0.203505 420:0.169885 421:0.0601984 422:0.0619023 423:0.149432 424:0.095661 425:0.119704 426:0.185102 427:0.249644 428:0.249644 429:0.2331 430:0.172669 431:0.0571165 432:0.0554624 433:0.105544 434:0.124474 435:0.204209 436:0.149226 437:0.287671 438:0.233312 439:0.158538 440:0.085772 441:0.102165 442:0.117022 443:0.122671 444:0.160237 445:0.151971 446:0.143499 447:0.129942 448:0.0959389 449:0.0556028 450:0.0864025 451:0.167466 452:0.0568043 453:0.105169 454:0.28099 455:0.287671 456:0.287671 457:0.203573 458:0.0838686 459:0.125802 460:0.19001 461:0.0978778 462:0.118772 463:0.103927 464:0.206477 465:0.221949 466:0.147634 467:0.109453 468:0.21046 469:0.0934628 470:0.111775 471:0.0854255 472:0.0896416 473:0.0980298 474:0.0729928 475:0.101601 476:0.0468797 477:0.0791986 478:0.158492 479:0.162197 480:0.188256 481:0.310893 482:0.298819 483:0.152905 484:0.154461 485:0.104955 486:0.219529 487:0.105981 488:0.109796 489:0.0943929 490:0.116314 491:0.211338 492:0.183864 493:0.15099 494:0.0466525 495:0.0814759 496:0.0826441 497:0.133331 498:0.189644 499:0.310893 500:0.310893 501:0.310893 502:0.178649 503:0.0622459 504:0.0721505 505:0.161893 506:0.112677 507:0.17197 508:0.261516 509:0.231606 510:0.12838 511:0.119647 512:0.0897209 513:0.204429 514:0.258437 515:0.151017 516:0.232684 517:0.106046 518:0.119519 519:0.118933 520:0.102533 521:0.109681 522:0.261516 523:0.0781687 524:0.0865439 525:0.120502 526:0.261516 527:0.261516 528:0.261516 529:0.0982907 530:0.0651658 531:0.0631546 532:0.205084 533:0.151398 534:0.215174 535:0.0894046 536:0.133384 537:0.157612 538:0.100458 539:0.0809739 540:0.148817 541:0.239039 542:0.163965 543:0.24837 544:0.147138 545:0.137003 546:0.198188 547:0.0955781 548:0.0704638 549:0.201737 550:0.09251 551:0.13307 552:0.203236 553:0.230284 554:0.24581 555:0.24837 556:0.163676 557:0.0441309 558:0.05486 559:0.200242 560:0.18874 561:0.24837 562:0.122286 563:0.111089 564:0.170059 565:0.0974838 566:0.0557162 567:0.139893 568:0.142029 569:0.135066 570:0.239535 571:0.165015 572:0.151529 573:0.215339 574:0.109499 575:0.0477798 576:0.102104 577:0.142869 578:0.0506508 579:0.099281 580:0.311296 581:0.311296 582:0.29235 583:0.0853785 584:0.0298867 585:0.0839334 586:0.217339 587:0.102943 588:0.0936696 589:0.0937782 590:0.148731 591:0.120643 592:0.0644866 593:0.105494 594:0.223154 595:0.124304 596:0.0630043 597:0.0882641 598:0.290856 599:0.311296 600:0.311296 601:0.159524 602:0.0136488 603:0.0657668 604:0.204307 605:0.149414 606:0.111302 607:0.106827 608:0.11079 609:0.117657 610:0.0400945 611:0.0877738 612:0.183063 613:0.133036 614:0.11257 615:0.114527 616:0.079359 617:0.144871 618:0.166868 619:0.0980467 620:0.0701586 621:0.136393 622:0.144127 623:0.204131 624:0.184349 625:0.273352 626:0.273352 627:0.273352 628:0.117483 629:0.0403787 630:0.101049 631:0.154879 632:0.180959 633:0.167622 634:0.138856 635:0.0361039 636:0.0806388 637:0.0373684 638:0.0916881 639:0.156742 640:0.223871 641:0.273352 642:0.271826 643:0.273352 644:0.165789 645:0.124406 646:0.0731598 647:0.143914 648:0.174675 649:0.112238 650:0.164751 651:0.0874189 652:0.161027 653:0.280177 654:0.223749 655:0.0456342 656:0.0362706 657:0.0407592 658:0.236262 659:0.280177 660:0.280177 661:0.0951557 662:0.137062 663:0.0833213 664:0.0380415 665:0.0730444 666:0.0742162 667:0.173875 668:0.280177 669:0.210483 670:0.195704 671:0.156123 672:0.0756225 673:0.0553245 674:0.106288 675:0.11255 676:0.231428 677:0.280177 678:0.280177 679:0.132035 680:0.0793173 681:0.0650503 682:0.0857836 683:0.126709 684:0.141397 685:0.215868 686:0.298669 687:0.298669 688:0.208136 689:0.0907796 690:0.0632681 691:0.0523893 692:0.0769242 693:0.0955798 694:0.0874953 695:0.098873 696:0.244548 697:0.186292 698:0.111636 699:0.105521 700:0.0849176 701:0.0982519 702:0.0771137 703:0.180454 704:0.298669 705:0.298669 706:0.255643 707:0.0955855 708:0.0588408 709:0.0775926 710:0.161626 711:0.132766 712:0.078477 713:0.0844616 714:0.298669 715:0.242583 716:0.107347 717:0.0798445 718:0.0853468 719:0.103689 720:0.065806 721:0.0357221 722:0.0298848 723:0.0814559 724:0.167687 725:0.266033 726:0.266033 727:0.250278 728:0.0899015 729:0.0693378 730:0.074513 731:0.0717591 732:0.120642 733:0.0856944 734:0.0741726 735:0.111318 736:0.0733351 737:0.111474 738:0.102383 739:0.0333341 740:0.0476535 741:0.090083 742:0.119321 743:0.266033 744:0.266033 745:0.266033 746:0.266033 747:0.186286 748:0.126744 749:0.0692135 750:0.161342 751:0.110722 752:0.266033 753:0.180974 754:0.180172 755:0.266033 756:0.23479 757:0.117383 758:0.159488 759:0.246485 760:0.240844 761:0.0489906 762:0.0327636 763:0.0302243 764:0.0614286 765:0.0963371 766:0.174301 767:0.246485 768:0.246485 769:0.246485 770:0.0998213 771:0.0707082 772:0.0477948 773:0.138016 774:0.121114 775:0.204169 776:0.113 777:0.246485 778:0.220392 779:0.246485 780:0.113499 781:0.046402 782:0.0894608 783:0.168363 784:0.192057 785:0.17405 786:0.246485 787:0.221395 788:0.227333 789:0.139138 790:0.0606163 791:0.0669251 792:0.162615 793:0.168169 794:0.264854 795:0.243766 796:0.140564 797:0.0976328 798:0.0677347 799:0.0445176 800:0.15511 801:0.15869 802:0.264854 803:0.264854 804:0.246155 805:0.104299 806:0.0436364 807:0.0780234 808:0.131923 809:0.166165 810:0.2136 811:0.132863 812:0.238265 813:0.157387 814:0.103066 815:0.151245 816:0.096932 817:0.0574446 818:0.107677 819:0.132774 820:0.238755 821:0.264854 822:0.112574 823:0.141528 824:0.182357 825:0.106048 826:0.12458 827:0.150181 828:0.164209 829:0.24785 830:0.24785 831:0.24785 832:0.191579 833:0.0602815 834:0.0766117 835:0.118639 836:0.180041 837:0.177137 838:0.0915748 839:0.10766 840:0.24785 841:0.199659 842:0.0899677 843:0.130194 844:0.105077 845:0.0814451 846:0.0724681 847:0.220688 848:0.24785 849:0.145892 850:0.207808 851:0.151263 852:0.0936182 853:0.13452 854:0.151408 855:0.202105 856:0.107693 857:0.143771 858:0.233332 859:0.201684 860:0.184008 861:0.147185 862:0.120236 863:0.101269 864:0.155512";
std::vector<float> floats;
float temp;
std::string eater;
std::stringstream ss(line);
while (std::getline(ss, eater, ':')) // eat input till : and toss out :
{
    ss >> temp;
    floats.push_back(temp);
}
```

Also in C++ it is not considered good practice to use

```
typedef struct {
    char index[2]; ////for example 1-99
    char filler[1]; //for ":"
    float value;  // for "0.0516209"
    char space[1]; // for " "
}img_vector;
```

Instead you should use

```
struct img_vector{
    char index[2]; ////for example 1-99
    char filler[1]; //for ":"
    float value;  // for "0.0516209"
    char space[1]; // for " "
};
```

Comment: So what a Different for use typedef struct or struct ? @NathanOliver

Comment: @FranksyeSipangkar `typedef struct {}img_vector;` creates an anonymous `struct` and then gives it a name via a `typedef` where as `struct img_vector{};` just creates a named `struct`.  The first version is used in C so you don't have to write `struct struct_name` everywhere you use the `struct` but in C++ you don't have to do that so there is no reason for the `typedef`

Comment: You said, in img_vector only allocate space for a 2 digit index `char index[2]; ////for example 1-99)` but the indexes in  data go up to 3 digits, I know it because from 1 - 864.So, for the +1, what I gonna do ? @NathanOliver